# Rotating repeated Image Texture/ Tile a Texture in 90° increments

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, uv-image-editor

I am trying to figure out how to randomly rotate an image texture that I apply to a simple plane.
So basically, I have an image of tiles and I would like to have "the duplicates" to rotate randomly by scaling the UV Map.

[image: Repeating Texture]

[image: Scaled UV Map]

After some days of researching I found some Videos and Blogs regarding this matter. Unfortunately neither of the proposed solutions were applicable to my problem. Most often, the solution was in regards in how to randomize an image texture over a large plane by rotating it in a random degrees (to tile a texture without repetition > BlenderGurus Video for example). In my case I just want to have the texture rotating in 90° increments. I'm relatively new to Blender and still learning how to use Nodes, so I would appreciate if somebody could help  me out or push me into the right direction, maybe even give me an alternative way of to this.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 8):

A possible node settings:

[image]

Use a *"vector rotate"* node with UV as input and a random rotation around z.

The random rotation is given by picking one random value per tile:

- Take the floor part of the UV (so one value per tile)
- Use a white noise to get a random value between 0 and 1
- Multiply by 4 as we want 4 cases: 0, 90, 180, 270°
- Take the floor of that to be aligned to the integer values
- Multiply by `pi/2` to obtain the rotation in radians

[image]